# Selenium C# in.net 6.0 is required to create the download directory for the Edge browser

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to set the download directory of the Chromium Edge browser for selenium during automation.

For Chrome I could achieve this using ChromeOptions like this:

```
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
```

I need to do the same for the Chromium Edge browser. How to download the files inside a customized folder, rather than the default Downloads folder in our system.

Comment: You can do it form the same way done it for Chrome.

Comment: No I need to do for Edge browser, am able to do for chrome browser successfully. I don't see setExperimentalOption  method on EdgeOptions class.

Comment: If you wan it for Edge, I am adding the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `path` in `Edge` using below.

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
options.setCapability("ms:inPrivate", true);

Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);

options.setCapability("ms:edgeOptions", prefs);

WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Although I don't see a setCapability function in the EdgeOptions class, thanks Akzy.

Comment: is this does not work ?

Comment: EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();                      
edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", pathForDownloads);
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
Like this am able to achieve this Thanks akzy..

Comment: @PradeepJuloori - Happy this help you. Please accept the answer, to help others.